# Mutlidimensional array not sorting with PHP usort correctly

Tags: php, usort

I can't get this. Why doesn' this work?

```
    $list = array(array('id' => 123), array('id' => 10), array('id' => 1000));
    $this->OrderListById($list);
    return $list;

    public function OrderListById($list){
        usort($list, function($a, $b) {return $a['id'] - $b['id'];});
    }
```

This returns

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => (int) 123
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => (int) 10
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => (int) 1000
    )
)
```

And i was hoping something like more ordered :D

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => (int) 10
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => (int) 123
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => (int) 1000
    )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$list` parameter in the `OrderListById` must be a reference:

```
public function OrderListById(array &$list)
{
    usort($list, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    });
}
```

Should work.

As a precaution you could typecast values as you compare them, just in case they are not integers, however, that's something you should check before you sort the array:

```
return (int) $a['id'] - (int) $b['id'];
```

Comment: Ha! It's always something simple, isn't it. Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

`return $a['id'] - $b['id'];`

1000-123 is more than 123-10.

This should be more like the example, where you do a comparison, not subtraction.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

In one line that would be:

```
usort($list, function($a, $b) {return ($a['id'] == $b['id'] ? 0 : (($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1)); });
```

(not tested, might be a typo, but that's the jist of it)

Comment: Working solution as well. Implementation is messier than what I was looking for :D

Answer (score -1):

Either pass by Reference:

```
public function OrderListById(&$list){
    usort($list, function($a, $b) {return $a['id'] - $b['id'];});
}
```

or return the sorted list

```
public function OrderListById($list){
    usort($list, function($a, $b) {return $a['id'] - $b['id'];});
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but seems like you hit the answer button in a hurry

Comment: Gee, how many downvotes am I actually going to get for answering hastily (even if the answer is formatted cleanly now)